# Symfony & Doctrine: persisting a many to one entity on an embedded form collection

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

Currently in a bit of a pickle. I have 2 entities: Main and Sub, it is a OneToMany relationship (one main can have many subs) I made a collection of form embedded together. I first had a search form where a user can search a Main by one of its attributes, then it sends them to a page where there is a form with the searched Main, its attributes listed on the form but is disabled so users cannot edit them, and the enabled fields are from the embedded Sub form which users need to enter in for submission.

1) User searches Main by its attribute, i.e. "pono" (PO number)
2) User is redirected to a page that shows the row that he/she searched for with the listed (pono), (cano), (bano) - it is disabled so it cannot be edited
3) Enabled fields are empty and users must enter the information that would be submitted into the Sub entity.

In my Main entity

```
 /**
 * @var Sub
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Sub", mappedBy="mainId")
 */
protected $sub;

public function __construct() {
    $this->sub = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

And my Sub entity:

```
 /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="main_id", type="integer")
*/
protected $mainId;

 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Main", inversedBy="sub", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="main_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $main;
```

In my Main form:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('pono', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'PO: ',
                'disabled' => true
            ))
        ->add('cano','text', array(
                'label' => 'CA: ',
                'disabled' => true
            ))
        ->add('bano', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'BA: ',
                'disabled' => true
            ))
        ->add('sub', 'collection', array('type' => new SubType()));
}
```

In my Sub form:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('qty','integer', array(
                'label' => 'Qty: '
            ))
        ->add('location','text', array(
                'label' => 'Location: '
            ))
        ->add('priority','text', array(
                'label' => 'Priority: '
            ));
}
```

So on my controller

```
 public function submitItemAction(Request $request, $pono) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('ItemBundle:Main')
        ->findOneByPono($pono);

    $cano = $entity->getCano();
    $bano = $entity->getBano();

    $main = new Main();
    $main->setPono($pono);
    $main->setCano($cano);
    $main->setBano($bano);

    $sub = new Sub();
    $sub->setMain($main);
    $main->getSub()->add($sub);

    $form = $this->createForm(new MainType(), $main, array(
            'method' => 'POST'
        ))
        ->add('submit','submit');

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($sub);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('success'));

    }
```

Now when this is submitted, it's submitting BOTH Main and Sub. It's giving me a duplicate Main and the newly added Sub. I know it is what it's supposed to do, but I need it to only submit the Sub. I tried retrieving the `id` from Main with a `$mainid = $entity->getId();` and putting it into `$sub->setMainId($mainid)` and I keep getting the error message that `main_id` cannot be null.

Any takers?
Edit: Twig template:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
            {{ form_label(form.pono) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.pono) }} <br>

            {{ form_label(form.cano) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.cano) }}<br>

            {{ form_label(form.bano) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.bano) }} <br>

            {% for sub in form.sub %}
                {{ form_label(sub.qty) }}
                {{ form_widget(sub.qty) }} <br>

                {{ form_label(sub.location) }}
                {{ form_widget(sub.location) }} <br>

                {{ form_label(sub.priority) }}
                {{ form_widget(sub.priority) }}<br>

            {% endfor %}
        {{ form_widget(form.submit) }}
        {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at your code, I think it is possible to make it work, there are a few things you will need to fix. I will edit this answer in a few steps.. Also make a backup/commit of your code before you start changing it.

1) In your MAIN entity (add cascade persist)

```
 /**
 * @var Sub
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Sub", mappedBy="main", cascade={"persist"}) 
 */
protected $sub;
```

2) SUB entity:

Remove protected $mainId; and it's annotation.

Remove cascade={"persist"} from ManyToOne

3) Look at your controller action.

```
$sub = new Sub();
$sub->setMain($main);
$main->getSub()->add($sub);
```

Pay attention to the setMain() method. You do not want to do this in controller, but automatically in entity. And also you should add to collection manually, but make a method for it. So you will only have this:

```
$sub = new Sub();
$main->addSub($sub);
```

4) In MAIN entity add (you might need to import Sub):

```
public function addSub(Sub $sub) {
    $sub->setMain($this);
    $this->sub->add($sub);
    return $this;
}
```

You should also add other methods like removeSub(), removeSub(), getSub(). getSub() returns collection, while the first two will return $this.

5) Controller

Do not persist Sub, but Main. (Doctrine will cascade persistance to Sub)

```
$em->persist($main);
```

6) You will need to add 'by_reference' option to sub collection inside you Main Form Type.

```
->add('sub', 'collection', array('type' => new SubType(), 'by_reference' => false));
```

This will call the actual addSub() method and not call the add method directly.

7) I do not know why you make a new Main entity below.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entity = $em->getRepository('ItemBundle:Main')
    ->findOneByPono($pono);

$cano = $entity->getCano();
$bano = $entity->getBano();

$main = new Main();
$main->setPono($pono);
$main->setCano($cano);
$main->setBano($bano);
```

Try to change to:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$main = $em->getRepository('ItemBundle:Main')
    ->findOneByPono($pono);
```

You probably should define Pono as unique.

Comment: is this going to affect my other functions? I have repository with queries that will display data by joins.

Comment: If you use mainId in your queries in repository, I suggest you fix them. You will probably just need to change from 'mainId' to 'main'. I think you won't be using the integer as id anymore, but you can join by the actual main object. Just a few more minutes so I can complete the answer.

Comment: it is still replicating the Main entity when I submit. Was I supposed to take away all the set methods in my Main form?

Comment: I have added step num 7. Does that help?

Comment: since I got rid of the $mainId and its annotation, my $sub annotation is mapping it (@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Sub", mappedBy="mainId", cascade={"persist"}) and it is giving me a 500 Internal Error, "Notice: Undefined index: mainId in ....."

Comment: Change 'mainId' to 'main'.

Comment: The database submission worked perfectly!! Thank you!! One last question, the form in the twig is looping through each Sub form that already exists with information and at the bottom there's a blank form for users to enter Sub information. How do I get it to not loop and only show an empty form?

Comment: I do not really understand the question. Please add your .html.twig to the question, so I can take a look.

Comment: Added. The {% for sub in form.sub %} loops through the Subs that already exists with the main, and displays an empty Sub form at the end. I don't need the loops, just the empty form. I tried to take away the loop but it won't identify the Sub form without it.

Comment: Replace the for loop with this:

{{ form_row(form.sub.vars.prototype) }}

Or without label:

{{ form_widget(form.sub.vars.prototype) }}

I hope it renders ok:)

Comment: sorry! Got this error: Key "prototype" for array with keys "value, attr, form, id, name, full_name, disabled, label, multipart, block_prefixes, unique_block_prefix, translation_domain, cache_key, read_only, errors, valid, data, required, max_length, pattern, size, label_attr, compound, method, action, submitted, allow_add, allow_delete" does not exist in ....html.twig

Comment: It works on my project well (I tested it before writing). I do not know where the problem might be, maybe you do something in Sub Form Type with the prototype? Try to google on how to only render the prototype of the collection. Keep in mind, it should be defined in form view vars.

Comment: how do you have your twig template?